# Disable script tag in html file or change script tag type/src using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the script tag or if its possible to change script `src` or `type` in this script using javascript?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./1.js.download"></script>`

I can't add `id` in this code.

please help and feel free to ask anything if you don't understand

Answer (score 2):

How about removing it altogether? The example is a simple function that get an element by the given `selector` and remove it. FYI if you don't want the `<script>` to actually load, then your'e out of luck. It'll be parsed as long as it's in the HTML, there's no way to avoid it from loading by JavaScript.

In the example there are 3 `<script>` tags and the target is in the middle. `document.querySelector("script")` will stop at the first match so you'll need a more specific selector. To target the second tag I used `script:nth-of-type(2)`. You can verify success using by <kbd>F12</kbd>

```js
const killTag = selector => document.querySelector(selector).remove();

killTag(`script:nth-of-type(2)`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./1.js.download"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @zer0One Yes that is also a good solution. +1 from me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove src from script tag like this:

```js
s = document.querySelectorAll('script')
console.log(s[1])
s[1].setAttribute('src', '')
console.log(s[1])
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="./1.js.download"></script>
```

You will have maybe multiple scripts in your dom. then you have take a look which element it is and change the key from the collection. in this case the key was 1.

Comment: i am really sorry to say... but why its not working..

Comment: @Utsho what exactly not working? you can share the relevant output in your console!?

Comment: `<script>
s = document.querySelectorAll('script')
console.log(s[1])
s[1].setAttribute('src', '')
console.log(s[1])
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//seamchristmas.com/2d/f9/08/2df90852c2b237080143f0e16c100af1.js"></script>`

Comment: @malik i tried using this but popads never stop.. please advise me.. how to solve it

Comment: @Utsho  I don't know your dom/html. But to explain: If you have 3 scripts in your HTML and the particular script is the last script in your HTML, then you have to write [2] instead of [1].

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select specific `script` element you can get it by attribute like this:

```js
let ok = document.querySelector('[src="./1.js.download"]');
//Then you can either change id or type:
ok.setAttribute('id', 'ok');
ok.setAttribute('type', 'module');
```